# How switch maven projects?

Tags: java, maven

Let me start from example. Suppose there is Factory inteface and Customer class:

```
public interface CustomerFactory(){
    Customer create();
}

public class Customer(){
    private String name;

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Suppose I have *CustmerProject* maven project that needs a *CustomerFactory*. I wan to create several maven projects with *CustomerFactory* implementation (one implementation per project of cource), but I does not want that *CustmerProject* will be depeneded of all these implemetation projects. I want to create one *CustomerFactoryIntefaceProject* that *CustmerProject* will be depend on and put one of *CustomerFactoryImplementationProject* as CustomerFactoryIntefaceProject. I know that this is possible, but how I can do that in practice?

**P.S.** If question is not clear ask me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution that very similar to Macias's post, but from real code.

The main idea is to put an stub class into "interface" project, add plugin that will delete stub classes during process-classes phase, make "implementation" project depends on "interface" and create class with real code with the same package and class name as stub.

Let's look slf4j project as example, you can download sources from http://www.slf4j.org/download.html

The main project is **slf4j-api** that contains interfaces: *Logger*, *LocationAwareLogger*(extends *Logger*), *ILoggerFactory* and other, also it contains *LoggerFactory* class (and several Utility classes), which is used when logger created for example:

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeClass.class);
```

This is "inteface" API.

For "implementation" API **slf4j-api** project contains impl package with 3 stub classes: *StaticLoggerBinder*, *StaticMarkerBinder* and *StaticMDCBinder* which methods used in *LoggerFactory* class, but in **slf4j-api** project they throw UnsupportedException.

Now let's look at **slf4j-jdk14** project that depends on **slf4j-api** and contains only impl package with 3 previous mentioned classes: *StaticLoggerBinder*, *StaticMarkerBinder* and *StaticMDCBinder*; and *JDK14LoggerAdapter*, *JDK14LoggerFactory* that implements *LocationAwareLogger* and *ILoggerFactory* from **slf4j-api**. But they aren't stub, they has a real code, for example *StaticLoggerBinder* returns *JDK14LoggerFactory* which produces *JDK14LoggerAdapter*.

Now let's look the place where Maven magic comes on. Recall that both "inteface" and "implementation" projects has the same classes *StaticLoggerBinder*, *StaticMarkerBinder* and *StaticMDCBinder*. Look at **slf4j-api** *pom.xml* and find build tag:

```
<project>
    ...
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    ...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <echo>Removing slf4j-api's dummy StaticLoggerBinder and StaticMarkerBinder</echo>
                    <delete dir="target/classes/org/slf4j/impl"/>
                </tasks>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    ...
</project>
```

Because **slf4j-jdk14** depends from **slf4j-api**, **slf4j-api** is builded first, after than plugin delete stubs and **slf4j-jdk14** is continued building and puts actual "implementations" classes "instead of" stubs.

Comment: The SLF4J solution works really badly in OSGi environments, and even Ceki admits it's not very modular. He's stuck maintaining backwards compatibility, but for a new design it's probably a better idea to consider an alternative solution such as DI or service lookup (e.g. java.util.ServiceLoader).

Comment: Can give a link with detail about problem with OSGi?

Comment: This thread is the best I can find right now. I'll see if I can find a quote from Ceki. http://mailman.qos.ch/pipermail/slf4j-dev/2012-October/003714.html

Answer (score 1):

You can parametrize the artifactId or version of CustomerFactoryImplementationProject and use maven profiles to choose the implementation during the build.

Say you have following artifacts:

- customer
- customer-factory-1
- customer-factory-2

So in the pom.xml of the customer project you will need:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>base</groupId>
    <artifactId>${customer.factory.artifact}</artifact>
    <version>123</version>
</dependency>
....
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>customerFactory1</id>
        <properties>
            <customer.factory.artifact>customer-factory-1</customer.factory.artifact>
        </properties>
     </profile>
     <profile>
        <id>customerFactory2</id>
        <properties>
            <customer.factory.artifact>customer-factory-2</customer.factory.artifact>
        </properties>
     </profile>
</profiles>
```

And now just choose the profile during the build like this:

```
mvn -P customerFactory2 install
```

---

... or actually you can profile the dependency block directly:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>customerFactory1</id>
        <dependencies>
             <dependency>
                 <groupId>base</groupId>
                 <artifactId>customer-factory-1</artifact>
                 <version>123</version>
             </dependency>
        </dependencies>
     </profile>
     <profile>
        <id>customerFactory2</id>
        <dependencies>
             <dependency>
                 <groupId>base</groupId>
                 <artifactId>customer-factory-2</artifact>
                 <version>123</version>
             </dependency>
        </dependencies>
     </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: ok, but what about java classes? In base project I must write something like this "StaticClass.geFactory()" which returns CustomerFactoryImpl from customer-factory-1 or customer-factory-2 projects, but how I can write this code, if I do not know what implementation will be used?

Comment: The project should not compile using any implementation class. The factory should return an Interface object, actually being an unknown implementation class instance. For that add to the maven dependency `<scope>runtime</scope>`.

Comment: I assume that both customer-factory-1 and 2 provide the CustomerFactoryImpl in same package. You can also set one of those profiles active by default, other way the IDE may probably be confused a bit